# how to fix: the lock core came out and it's still locked?

Tags: lock, carpentry

I captured a photo for The problem, the core came out and the key just rotating 360 degree with no effect.[image]
any help please?

Comment: Can you reach into the back of the lock with a thin tool and manipulate the actuator?

Comment: Does it look like the very rearmost part of the core is broken off and still in the lock? A sharp photo of the side and rear of the core might help.

Answer (score 1):

If a prybar won't deflect the top enough to open the drawer, take a hacksaw blade and saw off the locking bolt.